# Javascript array object in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code snippet in jquery.In which,I want to animate each element of array one by one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function AnimateText() {
            var myCars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
            myCars.each(function () {
                $(this).fadeIn("2000").fadeOut("2000");
            });

        }

    </script>
```

But I am getting this error **Object does not support this method or property**

**EDIT**

Thanks all for the answer.Now I have problem in animating the array element on the screen.

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default7.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default7" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AnimateText() {
            var myCars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
            $.each(myCars, function (key, value) {
                $("#myDiv").html(value).fadeIn("2000") ;
            });

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Animate" onclick="AnimateText();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the static [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
var myCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
// Capture this because inside the loop it will have a different meaning
var $this = $(this);
$.each(myCars, function () {
    $this.fadeIn("2000").fadeOut("2000");
});
```

You also probably want to show this text in some DOM element:

```
var myCars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
$.each(myCars, function () {
    $('#spinner').html(this).fadeIn("2000").fadeOut("2000");
});
```

where for example `spinner` is a div:

```
<div id="spinner"></div>
```

---

UPDATE:

After seeing your update it is more clear to me what you are trying to achieve. You could use the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) method:

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');
var myCars = ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW'];

$('#btnTest').click(function() {
    $.each(myCars, function(index, value) {
        var val = value;
        myDiv.delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
           myDiv.text(val);
        });
    });
});
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tWyFX/1/).

Comment: don't get this, inside loops jquery's this always refers to the current obj in the loop

Comment: @ezmilhouse, yes, that's why you might need to capture the one outside the loop. Anyway calling `.fadeIn` on a string doesn't make much sense, that's why I thought the OP needed to show this on some other object.

Comment: I am not getting any error,but I don't see any animation on the screen

Comment: @geek, where do you want to see the animation? You might need to use some selector: `$('.foo').fadeIn(...` in order to select the element where you want the animation to appear. Please see my updated answer for a sample.

Comment: you don't see any animation, because $this is not the jquery obj your looking for, just a wrong answer

Comment: @Darin:Your demo is working fine,but it's not working on my machine because of **delay**  function is missing in jquery-1.3.2 version.

Answer (score 1):

you should use it like this:

```
$.each(myCars, function(key, value){

    alert(value);

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1):

```
function AnimateText() {
    var myCars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
    $(myCars, function( key, value ) {
        $('#' + value).fadeIn("2000").fadeOut("2000");
    });
}
```

Better solution would be having html divs with IDs (Saab, Volvo, etc ...) and having a shared class .cars:

```
$(".cars").each(function(){
 $(this).fadeIn("2000").fadeOut("2000");
});
```

Comment: I tried your second approach.In this call all the div elements are fading and fade out at the same time ,but I want one by one

Comment: guess each is too fast, try to add a delay()

Answer (score 1):

This should be more close to what you are expecting from your code, I think :P

```
var myCars = Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW");
var currentCar = 0;
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');

function AnimateText() {
    var car = myCars[currentCar++];
    if (car) {
        myDiv.html(car).fadeIn('2000', function() {
            myDiv.fadeOut('2000', AnimateText);
        })
    }
}
```